# Ошибка в входе в систему

Tags: php

```
<?php
  session_start();

  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];

  if ($username && $password) {
      $connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","vladon12") or die("Невозможно подключиться");
      mysql_select_db("cdcol") or die("Невозможно подключиться");

      $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'");

      $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query)if ($numrows != 0)
      {
          while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
              $dbusername = $row['username'];
              $dbpassword = $row['password'];
          }

          if ($username == $dbusername && $password == $dbpassword) {
              echo "Добро Пожаловать, Нажми <a href='member.php'>здесь</a> для продолжения ";
              $_SESSION['username'] == $dbusername;
          } else
              echo "Неверный пароль";
      } else
          die("Такого пользоветеля нет в системе");
  } else
      die("Введите Логин и Пароль");
?>
```

Comment: Не могу найти ошибку ((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

я бы сделал как то так:

```
<?php
  session_start();

  $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
  $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
  //безопасность так её..

  if ($username && $password) {
      $connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","vladon12") or die("Невозможно подключиться");
      mysql_select_db("cdcol") or die("Невозможно подключиться");

      $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".$username."' AND password = MD5('".$password."')";
      //храним пароли в хешкоде )
      if(mysql_query($query))     
      {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
      ?>Добро Пожаловать, Нажми <a href='member.php'>здесь</a> для продолжения<?
      } else die("Данного сочетания логина и пароля не существует"); //так мы по крайней мере не палимся что введенный логин зареган
  } else
      die("Введите Логин и Пароль");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query) не хватает ";" в конце - это как минимум.

А вообще, вам нужно проверку соответствия введенных данных с данными в базе делать внутри цикла while. А у вас получается, что все записи прогоняете через while а потом последние значения пользователя и пароля сравниваете с введенными.

Answer (score 0):

Надо смотреть, что он вообще вытаскивает из базы. Сначала распечатайте для себя это на экране и сравнение

```
$username==$dbusername&&$password==$dbpassword
```

делать === 3 штуки, а не == две, так как тут буквенные и нецифровые данные и

```
$_SESSION['username'] == $dbusername;
```

убрать два равенства, а оставить одно, потому что тут присваивание, а не проверка.

Comment: >так как тут буквенные и не цифровые данные
а логин или пароль не может состоять из цифр что ли?

Comment: Может, но что лучше делать: проверять на равенство или соответствие? Сами подумайте.

Comment: И не имейте привычки хранить пароли в базе. Храните хэшкоды (на правах рекламы)

Comment: Согласен. Ибо в вашем случае потеря базы = потеря всех паролей.